# Accessing code-behind variables from page code

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I have the following two pages:

1. Default.aspx
2. Default.aspx.cs

How do I access variables in the code-behind file (Default.aspx.cs) from my embedded code in (Default.aspx) with the `<% %>` syntax?

Comment: Fixed!
I forgot to mark my variable as "public".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any `public` or `protected` (but *not* `private`, the "page" itself inherits from the code-behind `Page` class) class-level member can be accessed in this way.  For example, if your code-behind class has a property:

```
protected string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

Then in your aspx code you can refer to it:

```
<% =SomeValue %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply reference them as if they are part of the current class.

```
<%= this.Foo %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the access modifier for the variable the default is private and hence you cannot access it inside your page. It works for public, protected and friend. I prefer to use protected variables than public ones.