# Setting lang attribute of HTML tag

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to set the lang attribute of the HTML tag in webforms so that in the case of English, the output will be

`<html lang="en">`

This is how I do it; in markup, I have this:

```
<html id="SomeID" runat="server">
```

And in the code behind, I have this:

```
SomeID.Attributes.Add("lang", "en"); // or SomeID.Attributes.Add("lang", "fr");
```

The problem is that the actual output is

```
<html id="SomeID" lang="en">
```

The ID of the tag is still present so I tried adding this:

```
SomeID.Attributes.Remove("id");
```

But the ID is still showing.

So how do I set the lang attribute in my code-behind file so that the HTML tag only has the lang attribute.

Comment: Please try to use the search. The query ["asp.net html tag lang attribute"](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=asp.net+html+tag+lang+attribute) gave the mentioned duplicate and various others.

Comment: Actually, it's NOT a duplicate; for instance the answer you link to already does what's in the question. I'm asking how to set the language AND THEN remove the id="SomeID" attribute so that it doesn't show in the HTML output. For now, the output is <html id="SomeID" lang="en">

Comment: You can do it without even needing an ID attribute as shown in that question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: I tried but I wasn't able to access the control without giving it an ID. How do you reference the control? There's Page.FindControl(id) but it's taking a string(id) as a parameter so  that would still require to give the tag an ID?

Comment: You don't need to access the control; **create a variable in your code behind** and use it like suggested: `<HTML lang="<%= PageLanguage %>">`.

Comment: Ok, chanaged it to <HTML runat="server" lang="<%'PageLanguage'%>"> and now how do I set that string from the code behind to "en"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8491433/accessing-code-behind-variables-from-embedded-code and set it in the place where you had `SomeID.Attributes.Add("lang", "en");`.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I didn't know about page variables; I usually use literal controls when I need to put a string on the page. However here, I tried your solution and the output I get is <html lang="&lt;%&#39;PageLanguage&#39;%>">

Comment: You're welcome. To fix your last issue you need to change the HTML tag back to what is shown in the duplicate question.

Comment: @CodeCaster: you should put your answer as a real answer because it solved my problem and I'm sure it'll help others too.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using Jquery:

This is what your html (aspx) should look like:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#SomeID').removeAttr('id');
    });
</script>


<html id="SomeID"  runat="server" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

And on the server code (aspx.cs):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SomeID.Attributes.Add("lang", "en");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add RegisteredScript and pass the language value to the javascript function. In HTML you can set add this attribute through that javascript function.